# Getting Latest Created data from a list of data using IN operator

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch the latest group of data based on given id from a table.

Here ..what I have tried..

```
SELECT * 
FROM service_provider_portfolio_photo 
where service_provider_portfolio_detail_id IN (2,3) order by created_on desc
```

OUTPUT:

Got all the list which have id (2,3).But I need to get the top first data from each id.Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a inner join on max created_on

```
SELECT * 
FROM service_provider_portfolio_photo  p 
inner join (
    select service_provider_portfolio_detail_id, max(created_on) max_date
    from service_provider_portfolio_photo
    where service_provider_portfolio_detail_id IN (2,3) 
    group by service_provider_portfolio_detail_id 
) t  on t.service_provider_portfolio_detail_id = p.service_provider_portfolio_detail_id
          and t.max_date = p.created_on
```

Comment: Thank you.Its working fine :) ..But i am getting 2 data from each id since I have duplicate created time. Here I need to get the top first data for each id .Any suggestion?

Comment: you mean that haev tow rows  with the same created_on in service_provider_portfolio_photo   table?

Comment: Thnk you. I got it